# Whenever i click on the primary menu options of my website then unwanted shape appears.Please suggest me how to remove it?

Tags: wordpress, web

Whenever i click on the top primary menu options of my website then unwanted dotted rectangle shape appears. This is my wordpress website and here i am using astra theme. Please see the attached screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAkGy.jpg) below for more clarity of this issue.Please tell me how i can remove or rectify this because it looks so unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser adds this to `<a>` elements, when they become “active” or “focused” (e.g. clicked). You can disable this behavior by adding this to `style.css`:

```
:focus {
    outline: none;
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

Consider adding new focus styles of your own because that outline we just disabled was intended for accessibility.

Comment: I have pasted that above code but still that problem persist.Please solve this issue.

Comment: Can you maybe add a link to your website where the issue occurs?

Comment: Looked at your website - above code should work.. Try Method 1 here to add the css through the dashboard: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/